# looking for .net color quantizer libraries

Tags: c#, image-processing, colors

Are there any .net color quantization libraries out there other than [nQuant](https://nquant.codeplex.com/)?

I'm currently using nQuant in my program and it produces fantastically small files sizes however it has issues with grayscale gradients and gray shadows with transparency. Looking for alternatives to this library to use in my program.

I've also used [Color quantizer](http://x128.ho.ua/color-quantizer.html) which has a lot of flexible parameters but of course its a standalone application.

Hoping to not have to resort to calling external executable..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This one looks amazing and it has several different algorithims: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/66341/A-Simple-Yet-Quite-Powerful-Palette-Quantizer-in-C

I've used this one before http://members.ozemail.com.au/~dekker/NEUQUANT.HTML, a C# port of it can be found in the Gif.Components.NeuQuant class from this project http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/11505/NGif-Animated-GIF-Encoder-for-NET

Comment: The first one you linked to is very flexible but unfortunately very very slow compared to nQuant, even when the same algorithm (wu) is used.